# Arranging rows with alternating counts of items with CSS in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

Running into a strange issue trying to arrange items that are placed in multiple rows, each row containing either 5 or 4 items (alternating 5 items, 4 items, 5 items, etc...).  However, at 480px screen width, the layout switches simply to 2 items wide no matter how many in each row.  This creates a layout issue between the 4-item rows and 5-item rows.  When they're stacked on top of each other the rows with 4 work fine (2x2), but the rows of 5 have a hanging item/blank spot at the end of the box (2x2x1).

4/5 Row Layout:
[image]

2x2 row layout (with hanging item issue)
[image]

HTML:

```
<section id="rowArea">
   <div class="row fiveRow clearfix">
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row fourRow clearfix">
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row fiveRow clearfix">
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
        <div class="rowItem"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
/* Screen Width > 480px */
#rowArea {width:810px; height:auto; }
   .row {height:100px; }
   .fourRow {width:80%; padding:0 10%; }
      .fourRow .rowItem {width:25%; height:100px; float:left; }
   .fiveRow {width:90%; padding:0 5%; }
      .fiveRow .rowItem {width:20%; height:100px; float:left; }

/* Screen Width < 810px */
#rowArea {width:100%; height:auto; }

/* Screen Width < 480px */
#rowArea {width:100%; height:auto; }
   .row {height:100px; }
   .fourRow, .fiveRow {width:100%; padding:0 0; }
      .fourRow .rowItem, .fiveRow .rowItem {width:50%; height:100px; float:left; }
```

How do i restructure this/style this to eliminate the blank spot at the end of the 5-item rows?  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have the first row from the following set take up that blank spot or do you want separation between the three item rows?

Comment: I added images of the issue for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the `clearfix` class that is causing those gaps. A [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) class is meant to force an element to contain any floated child elements. Remove that class, and set your mobile css on .row to `height: auto` and the child elements should float against each other.

basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/gv5jL/1/